# Heavily compressing a PDF file

Tags: pdf, 7zip

I'm trying to compress a 180mb PDF file to less than 50mb. Hopefully this is the right community/place to ask, if not I apologize and can delete and move this post. All compression methods that I've tried through 7zip have yielded resulting files of around 55mb, which is tantalizingly close. I read about using precomp to decompress the PDF then re-compress it, but I couldn't figure out how to do it successfully. I have access to a PHP server that has ghostscript I think, but I'm not familiar with how to access it and utilize it. The PDF's contents are primarily complex technical drawings and some text blobs.
Any ideas on how I can achieve this level of compression?

Comment: Why is 7Zip important? Can you use any compression? If not, what compressions are you restricted to (e.g. zip, 7z, zlib, etc)?

Comment: I'm not limited to 7zip, but it's just the tool I'm using, so I can select zip, 7z, gzip, tar, etc

Comment: Note, the PDF format supports a lot of (good) compression options, so compressing a PDF may or may not result in much gain (depends on the particular PDF file). Anyway, I would suggest using Brotli compression. This paper is from the creators, so biased, but I assume the numbers are still accurate though. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brotli/vignettes/brotli-2015-09-22.pdf

Comment: (Author of precomp here) What are your problems using precomp? It should be as simple as opening up a terminal, running "precomp my_pdf.pdf" and (for decompression) use "precomp -r my_pdf.pcf" later. If 7-Zip alone reduces the PDF to 55 MB already, this should get it below 50 MB except if it contains some unsupported PDF streams.